# What advantages does this site have over Metaoptimize?

Tags: discussion

[Metaoptimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/) has been around for a few weeks and has accumulated a reasonably good set of questions, answers and users.
What does this site have to offer, to differentiate itself from Metaoptimize?

Answer (score 7):

Well, despite all the broohaha over the StackExchange business plan- I would say this site will benefit from the marketing power associated with being a StackExchange site.

More Users = More Questions = More Answers.

Case in point- this site has already attracted a large colonization of R users from Stack Overflow which is very exciting as in general these people know *both* the theory behind statistics and how to use tools to apply those theories to get results.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but MetaOptimize now seems to suffer from rather sticky problems.  The spam filtering is pretty much nonexistent, and right now, the site has been down for at least a couple of days -- in spite of being on CloudFlare.

Looking to me like the survival of the fittest ...

Comment: The site may appear down when it's not; it seems to load very slowly every time I visit. I'm guessing their server(s) suck(s).

Comment: I consistently see CloudFlare's 524 page since over a week back. I'm in Europe; maybe you are in a different region where there is no content delivery network between you and them? But if their CDN provider can't connect, either, that still means they are toast (and paying through their noses for a service which they seem to have caused to stop working).

Comment: The error page is now a 502 which suggests a more permanent error, but it's obviously been a few years since I last checked so I don't know when exactly this changed. They seem to still be wasting CloudFlare's resources ...

Answer (score 5):

One advantage is that Stack Exchange is online, whereas metaoptimize is off-line (disappeared overnight without any warning).

Comment: I think it's been effectively dead for some time.

Comment: @gung yes, it vanished around one year ago I believe.

Answer (score 4):

There is the same problem with BioStar and (planned) Bioinformatics. Still, I believe that the whole Area51 process is essential to gather a large, living community. Based on my example -- I didn't knew that Metaoptimize existed before you've mentioned it.

Comment: Same here- this is the first I have heard of Metaoptimize.  I think it's an awesome idea and I feel for the people that have put time into it- but marketing is one of the most powerful forces known to man. It is unfortunate that it usually takes money to get good marketing and that in many cases money won't touch open source with a ten-hundred-foot pole.

Answer (score 4):

This site also has things like meta, which we're using right now.  It's simply better software than the open-source equivalent.